# Java Vector: clear vs removeAllElements method

Tags: java

I'm new to Java.

Which is more efficient for Vectors -- clear() or removeAllElements().  I would guess removeAllElements since it leaves the capacity unchanged (doesn't release memory) whereas clear() releases memory.  Depending on the application, either may be desirable.

I would appreciate some input.  Thanks.

Comment: Consider using `ArrayList` as `Vector` is quite old school - only used by people reading old text books.

Comment: Agreed..  I did more research and have switched. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#removeAllElements%28%29) about the .removeAllElements() method.

> "This method is identical in
>   functionality to the clear method
>   (which is part of the List
>   interface)."

Answer (score 7):

[Vector](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) was in Java 1.1, and since Java 1.4 the new [Collection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) has appeared, defining a general [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface with the function clear().

Use clear(), because it is the modern API. Both functions are equivalent.

Btw. consider using [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of Vector. ArrayList is not synchronized, and so its faster if you don't access the List from different Threads simultanously.

Answer (score 2):

When you are worried about efficiency (and there’s quite a chance that you are for the wrong reasons), don’t use `Vector` at all, but use a `List` implementation (such as `ArrayList`) instead. If you are using `Vector` because of its internal synchronization (and I have my doubts about that), use a `synchronizedList` instead.

Also, `Vector.clear()` just calls `Vector.removeAllElements()` so there is no functional difference, just one more function call when using `Vector.clear()`. That being said, if you have to use `Vector`, call `Vector.clear()` because it adheres to the more modern `Collection` interface and states a clearer intent.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Was just using Vector since I come from a C++ STL background.  I will research Lists more.

Answer (score 1):

As in JavaDoc for [Vector.removeAllElements()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#removeAllElements%28%29):

> Removes all components from this
>   vector and sets its size to zero. This
>   method is identical in functionality
>   to the clear() method

So they are identical. `clear()` is better because of compliance with the newer Java Collections interface.